# In Aurelia Slickgrid how to get editor and filter collectionAsync data?

Tags: aurelia, slickgrid, stringify

I use aurelia 2 with import and JSON.stringify this import.
With the example #3, I tried to get the collectionAsync in Aurelia 2. The fetch method tell me that data presented to collectionAsync at filter option is not a valid array, some times is not a function or json error in line 1, column 2; All combinaison fail to work; how to use in lieu simple collection which is not actually work in my code?

Comment: why are you stringifying your import? The Example 3 has a `collectionAsync` on the Country of Origin list and it works correctly, collectionAsync is expecting either a Fetch result or a Promise with a collection (array) of `label`, `value` but if you want something different then use `customStructure`. You should take a look at the Docs

Comment: Thanks. The fetch give me results that complains not to ne valid array collection. I'd format it after to be an array and it works : dataset is accepted for array not countries data collection. I suspect strange behind json opération.

Comment: `collectionAsync` expect a certain structure, it tries to parse from Fetch, Http-Client or Promise, if it can't find any of that then it might throw, you should add breakpoints and troubleshoot the code, you can see the Slickgrid-Universal method implementation [renderCollectionOptionsAsync](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/3e002f15a06abd06893783e0667798f5ff8893cf/packages/common/src/filters/filterUtilities.ts#L52-L101). I can't help without a full repro, so you're on your own. You might also get downvoted here, not by me, since you did not provide any code/repro

Comment: Thanks much! It was a webpack configuration problem. Solved.